# How to change the host name displayed at the login screen

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I changed my MacBook Pro's hostname, but the login screen still shows the old hostname. Please could anyone help me to change this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Mac OS X Hostname Determination](http://excitedcuriosity.wordpress.com/2007/08/24/mac-os-x-hostname-determination/), in short adjust your `HOSTNAME` in /etc/hostconfig
and not only in Sharing-Preferences.

(Actually, there are 2 places in sharing-preferences where you may change your hostname, first the big textbox when you open up the preferencepane and second after you click on edit.)

Answer (score 1):

On 10.4 and 10.5 check the file 
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
on the bottom there are these lines:

```
        <key>HostNames</key>
        <dict>
            <key>LocalHostName</key>
            <string>*********</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>System</key>
    <dict>
        <key>ComputerName</key>
        <string>***********</string>
        <key>ComputerNameEncoding</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
```